# Determine the expected value of $\sin X$.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

DRV $X$ is equally likely to take the values $0^\circ\, , 45^\circ \, , 90^\circ$. Determine the expected value of $\sin X$.

*My attempt:*

I tried $\sum_{x=0}^3 \frac{\sin x}{3}$ but the answer is wrong...

Comment: $\frac13(0+1/\sqrt2 + 1)$ should be the answer.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected value is calculated as $$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^nX_ip_i$$
You have a random variable $X$ which can take values $0,45,90$ equally likely so the probability for each is $1/3$. You want expected values of $\sin X$, since $X$ takes 3 values calculate $\sin X$ at these values and multiply by the probability. $$E(\sin X)=\frac13(\sin0+\sin 45+\sin90)$$

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @yuyangchee98 In fact your attempt was also correct. Just that you forgot to substitute the different values of $x$.

Comment: ...not only. There were 4 values instead of 3 and the values where not $\sin(0),\sin(1),\sin(2),\sin(3)$...